# "Representability" of $\pi_1:\mathsf{hTop}_\ast \longrightarrow \mathsf{Grp}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, limits-colimits

In [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23145/when-does-a-representable-functor-into-a-category-other-than-set-preserve-limi), Qiaochu Yuan asks about limit preservation of "representable" functors which are not $\mathsf{Set}$-valued. The answer gives a simple sufficient condition, possessed by monadic functors.

I am confused about the problem with the example of $\pi_1:\mathsf{hTop}_\ast \longrightarrow \mathsf{Grp}$. First of all, what is the "extra structure" on $S^1$ and why is it needed for representability of $\pi_1$? The [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23145/when-does-a-representable-functor-into-a-category-other-than-set-preserve-limi#comment47917_23145) by Tilman points out $\mathsf{hTop}_\ast$ doesn't have limits, but why does this matter? Whatever limits do exists should be preserved, no? Does he mean that these limits do not coincide with homotopy limits on $\mathsf{Top}_\ast$, which are the geometrical constructions we're interested in?

Comment: $S^1$ is a cogroup. All you actually need is that the object you're representing with is a co-H-space (though I bet a homotopy theorist can tell me I need less).

Comment: Maybe a homotopy theorist woudl tell you you need more, since the OP only wants a functor into $\mathbf{Grp}$, not $\mathbf{Grpd}.$ :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. By default, when you talk about representable functors they have to be functors to $\text{Set}$. If you want them to take values in a more refined category that can sometimes happen if the representing object itself has additional structure. Here $S^1$ has the structure of a cogroup (in the pointed homotopy category), which corresponds to the group structure on $\pi_1$ by the Yoneda lemma.
2. Very few limits exist, and in any case what we want to compute are homotopy limits.

Comment: But, to be clear, $hTop_*(S^1,\bullet)$ does preserve those limits which exist, essentially just products.

Comment: What about $S^n$'s?

Comment: @Arrow: what about them? They are also cogroups because $\pi_n$ is also a group, again by the Yoneda lemma. (And in fact they have no more structure than this, in the following precise sense: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/the-homotopy-groups-are-only-groups/).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Then I don't understand - why this extra structure is relevant to representing $U\pi_n$?

Comment: @Arrow: I don't understand what you don't understand. I already said this: the extra structure is how you lift the represented functor from being set-valued to being group-valued.